# How to specify site path in Facebook developer app to work with www and without www in Rails?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4

I implemented login with Facebook in my application. And I specified `site path= http://www.myfitquest.com/` for Facebook developer app. But it is working only if I use http://www.myfitquest.com/ as URL not if I use http://myfitquest.com/. And I want it to work with both.

Programming language: Ruby on Rails 4

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by entering "myfitquest.com" in Application Domain under settings option.